# Why does letting air into a box of wine help the flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, air

I've notied that when I get down to the last part of a box of wine, the flow slows to a trickle.  If I open the nozzle, tilt the box back (letting air gurgle into the bladder) and then tilt it back forward the flow is greatly increased.

Why does letting air into the bladder help increase the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without air in the bag, the wine is all forced (by atmospheric pressure) to the bottom of the bag, which is below the tap. The bag itself is scrunched around the wine at the bottom of the box. That makes it more difficult for the wine to reach the tap, when the level is low, even if you tilt the bag. As long as the level of the wine is above the tap, there is no problem.

If you let air in, then the wine can slosh around in the bag, so that it can reach the tap more easily. This only helps when the wine level is getting very low, when access to the tap is obstructed. As long as most of the bag (and wine) is still above the tap this has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I guess when you pour wine the volume of air in the box increases, so air pressure in the box decreases, so a pressure differential is created between atmospheric pressure and air pressure in the box. This pressure differential limits the flow. When you let some air in the box, this pressure differential decreases.

Comment: This is correct, but it seems to me the questioner has no idea of how a vacuum can be created using the balance of air pressure and weight of fluid, as in the Toricelli barometer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelista_Torricelli.

Comment: You get the same effect with portable water coolers:if air is not allowed to enter the water stops flowing after a while, the air pressure balances the weight of water+low-pressure-air  left in the cooler.

Comment: In those boxes the wine is in a plastic bladder inside the box, so atmospheric pressure should keep forcing the wine out, regardless of the amount of wine left.

Comment: @hdhondt: Atmospheric pressure (outside of the box) is higher than air pressure in the box. How can it force the wine out?

Comment: @hdhondt, is correct.  The box is not air tight so the air pressure is the same.  There is a plastic bladder in the box that actually contains the wine, but air can easily go in and out of the box.

Comment: @Abe Miessler: I am afraid I don't quite get it. If the air box is not air tight, why cannot you pour wine from the box without opening it? It is not enough to open the box to equalize pressure, as the liquid (wine) interferes with such equalization. You may just try the following experiment: pour water into a bottle with a thin neck and then quickly flip the open bottle in such a way that it is vertical, but with the bottle neck being below the bottom. Water will leave the bottle relatively slowly, as air cannot freely enter the bottle, and there is a pressure differential.

Comment: @akhmeteli What you don't seem to realise is that it is not the box that holds the wine. What holds it is a plastic bag inside the box. The tap is attached to that bag, not to the box. During normal operation the bag collapses inside the box, forced down by air that leaks into the box, but not into the bag. This forces the wine out. Only when the bag has collapsed into a heap at the bottom of the box is there a problem. I didn't explain this in my answer, as I assumed (wrongly) that it is common knowledge.

Comment: @akhmeteli: in case it wasn't obvious in my previous comment, the bag is not stuck to the box. It is completely loose inside.

Comment: @hdhondt: Well, of course, I don't know exactly what box design the questioner had in mind. I had in mind boxes that I saw: They do contain a bladder, but it does not look like the pressure in the box always equals the atmospheric pressure after the box is open (in particular, the box is reasonably rigid).

Comment: @akhmeli. Sorry for the delay in coming back but, are you telling me that a piece of cardboard that's been folded and glued into a box with not only gaps at the joints, but also a large hole in the front (for the tap) is able to keep a appreciable pressure differential for more than a fraction of a second?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am telling you, until the opposite is proven. What gaps at the joints do you have in mind? And, as far as I  understand, the "large hole" provides communication with the internals of the bladder, not with the space between the bladder and the internals of the box.